# Declare array optimally for replylist in comment system

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am working on a comment system like youtube using [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js). Rest of it working fine but i found problematic on replylist part.

What have i done is i have declared an array for whole replylist then for each `commnet_id` as index i pushed an array of replies.

To me it will create a huge array of replylist when there will be lots of replies in the database.

So please suggest me an optimal way of declaring replylis for fetching data from database and also realtime on submit reply.

[Here is the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jahid93/Lb9ezxf0/).